# How to apply a function to an array of matrices and obtain an output in the same form (an array of matrices)

Tags: r, arrays, apply

Here is a trivial example of what I want:

```
x <- stats::rWishart(10, 3, matrix(c(4,1,1,3), nrow = 2))
apply(x, 3, function(m) {return(m + matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow=2))})
```

Clearly, one would want the output of this to be a 2x2x10 array (the same as the input). However, for some obscure reason, R automatically transforms matrix outputs to vectors, so that the code above actually returns a 4x10 matrix (instead of a 2x2x10 array).

How do I fix this ?

Comment: Yep unfortunately `apply` is designed for matrix work and arrays aren't very fun to use in R. See the docs: "In all cases the result is coerced by as.vector to one of the basic vector types before the dimensions are set" hence the dimension drop. You could also consider using lists of matrices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since R 4.10, there is a `simplify=` argument, to apply, which you can use to return a list, which can be simplified back to an array via `simplify2array`:

```
out <- simplify2array(
  apply(x, 3, function(m) {return(m + matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow=2))},
        simplify=FALSE))

dim(out)
#[1]  2  2 10
```

Or you can replace/overwrite the existing data:

Overwrite the original object:

```
x[] <- apply(x, 3, function(m) {return(m + matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow=2))})
```

Replace the contents of the original object and return a new object:

```
replace(x, , apply(x, 3, function(m) {return(m + matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow=2))}))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just reshape it ie:

```
x <- stats::rWishart(10, 3, matrix(c(4,1,1,3), nrow = 2))
y <- apply(x, 3, function(m) {return(m + matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow=2))})
array(y, dim(x))
```

If you could vectorize the function, then it would be better. for the addition, you could do:

```
x + array(1:4, dim(x))

array(c(x) + 1:4, dim(x))
```

Comment: The vectorisation approach is probably best, though you don't even need to get fancy with the array bits - just `x + 1:4` will do it - `identical( x + array(1:4, dim(x)), x + 1:4)`